# How do I do this calculation (1+1+1) in a Java GUI Calculator

Tags: java, swing

I have written some code in a calculator made from a Java GUI, however I can't seem to get multiple amount of numbers added (like 1+1+1) to get the correct answer. If I add 1+1+1 in my calculator, I get 2. How can I store in memory 1+1, then add 1 to get 3?

Here's the code:

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Calc {

    private JFrame frame;
    String buffer, operator;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calc window = new Calc();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Calc() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        
        JButton btnOne = new JButton("1");
        btnOne.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(Double.toString(1.0));
            }
        });
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("+");
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (buffer != "") {
                    double left = Double.parseDouble(buffer);
                    double right = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                    buffer = compute(operator, left, right);
                } else {
                    buffer = textField.getText();
                }
                textField.setText("");
        
            }
        });
        
        JButton btnEquals = new JButton("=");
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(4)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnOne)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 338, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(btnAdd)
                        .addComponent(btnEquals))
                    .addGap(21))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnOne)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd)
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addComponent(btnEquals))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static String compute(String operator, double left, double right) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "+" : return Double.toString(left+right);
        default  : return "ERR";
        }
    }

}
```

Have pasted whole code, but what I coded only adds two numbers, fairly obvious why, because only two numbers (double first and second) are added.

I would like it to add more numbers, before equals is pressed.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: There is too little code for us to be able to help. Please edit the question to show a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: basically, handling the (second) operation (e.g. `+`): do the previous calculation (first`+ `), move the result to the first input field )or variable - we cannot see the code), clear the second input field, remember the operation for when the next operation or equals is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You will need two variables:

1. A buffer (`String`) to store the previous input
2. The current operator (`String` or `enum`) (aka mode)

That's it.

You will need to update these variables, along with the buffer display and the current input value.

There are three button types:

1. Command (Clear, change sign, percentage, and equals)
2. Operator (+, -, *, /)
3. Digit (includes the decimal)

Now for your inquiry, you will need to detect if the buffer is not empty when you go to apply another operator:

```java
// Required variables
String buffer, operator;

// Inside operator keypress logic
if (buffer != "") {
    double left = Double.parseDouble(buffer);
    double right = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    buffer = compute(operator, left, right);
} else {
    buffer = textField.getText();
}
textField.setText(""); // Clear (buffer will display prev and operator)


// A pure function, defined anywhere
public static String compute(String operator, double left, double right) {
    switch (operator) {
        case "+" : return Double.toString(left + right);
        case "-" : return Double.toString(left - right);
        case "*" : return Double.toString(left * right);
        case "/" : return Double.toString(left / right);
        default  : return "ERR";
    }
}
```

The code below is a basic algorithm that can be applied to your Java Swing application with just two variables.

---

## Demonstration

Here is a basic example in JavaScript that describes the flow of a simple calculator.

```js
let buffer, operator;

const compute = (operator, left, right) => {
  switch (operator) {
    case '+': return left + right;
    case '-': return left - right;
    case '*': return left * right;
    case '/': return left / right;
    default:  return 'ERR';
  }
}

const handleClick = (e) => {
  const calculator = e.target.closest('.calculator');
  const dispBuffer = calculator.querySelector('.display > .buffer');
  const dispInput = calculator.querySelector('.display > input');
  
  switch (e.target.dataset.type) {
    case 'digit':
      dispInput.value += e.target.dataset.value;
      break;
    case 'operator':
      buffer = operator ? compute(operator, +buffer, +dispInput.value) : dispInput.value;
      operator = e.target.dataset.value;
      dispInput.value = '';
      dispBuffer.textContent = `${buffer} ${operator}`;
      break;
    case 'command':
      switch (e.target.dataset.value) {
        case 'AC':
          dispInput.value = '';
          operator = '';
          buffer = '';
          dispBuffer.textContent = '';
          break;
        case '+/-':
          dispInput.value = +dispInput.value * -1;
          break;
        case '%':
          dispInput.value = buffer ? +dispInput.value / 100 : 0;
          break;
        case '=':
          dispInput.value = compute(operator, +buffer, +dispInput.value);
          operator = '';
          buffer = '';
          dispBuffer.textContent = '';
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
};

document.querySelector('.keyboard').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid #DDD;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  background: #444;
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
}

.display .buffer {
  min-height: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.display > input {
  text-align: right;
  background: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
}

.keyboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.keyboard button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.grid-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="display">
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="0" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="keyboard">
    <button data-type="command" data-value="AC">AC</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="+/-">+/-</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="%">%</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="/">/</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="7">7</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="8">8</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="9">9</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="*">*</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="4">4</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="5">5</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="6">6</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="-">-</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="1">1</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="2">2</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="3">3</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="+">+</button>
    <button class="grid-span-2" data-type="digit" data-value="0">0</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value=".">.</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="=">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Update

Here is the fixed code. You need to be aware of `NullPointerException` stack traces. A debugger would have told you that the `operator` was null, because you never set it when clicking the addition button.

Use an `Optional.ofNullable(operator).orElse("")` to access it, create a convenience getter that guarantees the operator will always be a non-null string. Or never set it to null and always an empty string when resetting. You have many options.

Below, I just added a simple `null`-check around the `switch` statement.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Calc {

    private JFrame frame;
    String buffer, operator;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calc window = new Calc();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Calc() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 200);

        JButton btnOne = new JButton("1");
        btnOne.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String digit = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText(); // Get button text ("1"));
                textField.setText(textField.getText() + digit);
            }
        });

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("+");
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (buffer != null && buffer != "") {
                    double left = Double.parseDouble(buffer);
                    double right = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                    buffer = compute(operator, left, right);
                } else {
                    buffer = textField.getText();
                }
                operator = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText(); // Get button text ("+")
                textField.setText("");

            }
        });

        JButton btnEquals = new JButton("=");
        btnEquals.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                double left = Double.parseDouble(buffer);
                double right = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                textField.setText(compute(operator, left, right));
                operator = null;
                buffer = null;
            }
        });

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(4)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(btnOne)
                                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 338,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addComponent(btnAdd)
                                        .addComponent(btnEquals))
                                .addGap(21)));
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(5)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(btnOne)
                                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(5)
                                .addComponent(btnAdd)
                                .addGap(5)
                                .addComponent(btnEquals)));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String compute(String operator, double left, double right) {
        if (operator != null) {
            switch (operator) {
                case "+":
                    return Double.toString(left + right);
                default:
                    return "ERR"; // Unsupported operator
            }
        }
        return "ERR"; // Operator was null
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I apply the java snippet to my code? (hmm)

Comment: @user22190533 I explained what the Java code looks like already. You just need to add it t your code. Take a look at the JavaScript implementation to understand the flow of the logic.

Comment: Can't get it to work.

This part has type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String

```
 case "+" : return left+right;
```

Comment: @user22190533 Sorry, I updated the Java snippet. I forget to convert the double result of the arithmetic back into a String.

Comment: I added the buffer code inside the operator keypress logic, and launch the program. When I press the + sign, alot of errors appear

Comment: @user22190533 you will have to post your Swing application code (in its entirety). Also, are you using an IDE? Have you ran the debugger? Are you calling non-static methods inside of instance methods?

Comment: Added the entire code above  (using Eclipse)

Comment: @user22190533 added working code that fixes the null-pointer. Please use the Eclipse debugger and place breakpoints around the erroneous lines that the stack trace complains about.

Comment: Thanks dude...there's still an error if I press the + sign and then the = sign, but I'm sure there's a way to fix it...

Comment: I put an if statement in the operator keypress logic and also in the = logic, to popup a dialog box to say Stiring is empty, but pop up appears on first click only. Upon repeated clicking, the empty string stack traces appears....